# SPARQL Queries. 'Group by' and then 'count' certain items in group based on condition. Include items with a count of zero

Tags: database, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

I have a dataset containing many of the following 'Movies' in TURTLE RDF format. I have to list, in ascending order, 5 countries with the lowest number of horror movies and at least one drama or action movie . My logic behind working out the problem is as follows: Group the data by country, then within each group, count how many 'Movies' have 'Horror' within 'Genre'. So if a group contains no movies with 'Horror' within the genre then that would be counted as zero. Check if each group has at least one movie with genre containing 'Drama' OR 'Action'. The only examples I can find on W3 are very simple and I can't work out how to apply them to this problem as I am very new to SPARQL. My attempt at this is below the data example. It doesn't work but it gives an idea of what I am attempting to do. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
mov:Movie1 a mov:Movie;
  mov:Name "Movie1";
  mov:Country "Australia";
  mov:Genres "Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi";

mov:Movie2 a mov:Movie;
  mov:Name "Movie2";
  mov:Country "USA";
  mov:Genres "Action|Thriller|Horror|Sci-Fi";

...etc
```

```
select * {
    {        
        select ?country  {
        ?movie <country> ?country.
        ?movie <genres> ?genre .

        {
                select (count(regex(?genre, "Horror", "i" )) as ?horror_count){
                ?movie <genres> ?genre  
          }
        }
    } group by ?country  order by desc(xsd:integer(?horror_count)) limit 5
    }
    filter (regex(?genre, "Drama", "i" ) || regex(?))
}
```

Comment: what is `select (count(regex(?genre, "Horror", "i" )) as ?horror_count){
                ?movie <genres> ?genre  
          }` supposed to do?

Comment: you should start with the first part of the query, i.e. all countries with at least one movie of genre Drama or Action.

Comment: Count how many horror movies are within a group

Comment: hm, but you're not grouping here. subqueries are always evaluated first, it's bottom up evaluation.  `select ?country (count(?movie) as ?horror_count){
                 ?movie <country> ?country . OPTIONAL {?movie <genres> ?genre filter(regex(?genre, "Horror", "i" )) } } group by ?country` - try this query first